# Asp.Net entity framework core transactions across stored procedure calls

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, transactionscope

I usually allow EF to manage the transactions. In this case I am using one context but I am making multiple calls to stored procedures using FromRawSql and ExecuteSqlRaw. I'm not sure if this will be safely done in a transaction since I don't usually use stored procedures. If a procedure fails will all the procedures be rolled back? Do I need to explicitly create a TransactionScope?

Comment: No. Yes. EF has no way to know what you're intending, so it can't assume anything.

Comment: Okay that sounds simple enough, Thanks